# Import error for scipy.io module

Tags: python, scipy

I have a peculiar problem with the python module scipy.io. I am using Python 3.4 in a virtual emvironment. While I can import scipy within python, I get an error message importing scipy.io: "ImportError: /home/dv8000/virtualenv/venv-py3.4/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyTraceback_Add"

I can import scipy.io from python 2.7, not in the virtual environment, and I can import scipy.io within anaconda3, which has python 3.4. I've uninstalled scipy and reinstalled it a few times with variations, but without being able to recover scypy.io. I am developing a django appication, and I'm sure I could import scipy.io in the past. Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Walter

Comment: This is probably due to an update in the underlying python that you are using in the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks,  donkopotamus, I did copy python3.4 from outside my virtualenv, and created the proper python link, python3.4 -> python. I can now import scipy.io. This was a weird problem - thanks for the answer!